# storing images while download the .apk in sdcard?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on database project.That actually contain flash card structure. So for me i want to load some sample images in sdcard while installing .apk file on device.

I tried to put it on drawable but it will not allow me to use these image path in database for while using to show in application through database tables...

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend you seem to misunderstand how Android works..

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html) thoroughly before you ask any other weird question, please understand that what you are trying to achieve is impossible.

You cannot download anything until and unless your application is installed on the device, 
after you app starts you can write a service which downloads your images in background while the user interacts with your application.

Comment: I think you never get my question....i got the solution and i added it in my application. Actually i want to put some images in asset folder and write this images on sdcard while user download the application first time only. No wary thanks for reply me....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but you could use the `/assets` directory in your project, try looking at this [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).

Comment: Hey thanks buddy.....i got the solution....for it..but thank you for replying me....i try to put this logic on below this comment if any buddy require this please to use...R

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor;
    InputStream IS;
    private static int k=0;
    private String []dirname ={"Flowers","Animals"};
    private String []country={"Australia","Brazil","Iran","Japan","India"}; 
    private String []captial={"Canberra","Brasilia","Tehran","Tokyo","New Delhi"};
    private String []names={"Lotus","Mogra","Morning glory","Rose","Aster","Dog","Lion","Squirrel","Tiger","Wolf"};
    private File sdcard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_category);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application Preparing For First Time", 5000).show();
```

//Here the variableDeclaration is java class where i put database object as static for //whole application.

```
        VariableDeclaration.db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Animals " +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,path varchar,caption varchar,type int(1));");

        VariableDeclaration.db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Flowers " +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,path varchar,caption varchar,type int(1));");

        VariableDeclaration.db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Capitals " +
                "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,path varchar,caption varchar,type int(1));");


        AssetManager asset_items=this.getAssets();
```

//This is assetmanager who stores    the images from asset dir to this container.

```
        String []items=new String[10];

        try{

            items=asset_items.list("");

            for(int i=0;i<dirname.length;i++){
```

//FlashFlicker is my application dir name which created while .apk loads for first time.

```
                File file=new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"FlashFlicker"+File.separator+dirname[i]);
                file.mkdir();
```

//Here in this for loop i created some dir and copy sample images into it 5 in each dir.

```
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    IS=asset_items.open(items[k]);

                    File file1=new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"FlashFlicker"+File.separator+dirname[i]+File.separator+items[k]);
                    VariableDeclaration.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+dirname[i]+" VALUES (null,'"+file1.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"','"+names[k].toString()+"',"+i+");");

                    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file1);
                    byte[] buff=new byte[1024];

                    while(IS.read(buff)!=-1){
                        out.write(buff);
                    }
                    out.close();

                    k++;
                }

            }


        }catch(Exception e){}


        int j=2;
        for(int i=0;i<country.length;i++){
         VariableDeclaration.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Capitals VALUES (null,'"+country[i].toString()+"','"+captial[i].toString()+"',"+j+");"); 
        }
```